# How to convert ASCII(Unicode) code to Qt::Key_ code?

Tags: qt, unicode, ascii

For example:
'>' ->  0x3e    (Qt::Key_Greater)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the values of the `Qt::Key` enum correctly you do not need any conversion since the Qt::Key values are the same as the unicode values i.e. a cast would suffice:

```
Qt::Key_Greater == (Qt::Key) '>'
```

should be true for this particular key. There are of course other special keys where this does not make sense ...

Comment: What you say is true, though I did notice that it seems to use the values for the uppercase letters, so you get 65 (decimal) even for a lowercase 'a'. It seems at least that the keyPressEvent on QLineEdit doesn't care about this value anyway, so when generating synthetic keypress events one might well get away with the solution above.